# Make a PDF bookmark point towards title

Tags: bookmarks, etoolbox, patching

I've been using the bookmark package to add custom PDF bookmarks to my thesis. More specifically, I started using this package because I didn't want the the ToC, LoF and LoT to appear in the ToC, but still appear in the bookmarks bar.

The problem I've been encountering is that the `hypertarget` does not point towards the top of  the first page of the targeted section, but rather somewhere above it. The result is that as the ToC, LoF, and LoT get longer the hypertarget is more and more "off target".

Here's a MWE of the code I've been using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot,chapter]{tocbibind} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\hypertarget{tocpage}{}
\tableofcontents
\bookmark[dest=tocpage]{Table of Contents}

\hypertarget{lofpage}{}
\listoffigures
\bookmark[dest=lofpage]{List of Figures}

\hypertarget{lotpage}{}
\listoftables
\bookmark[dest=lotpage]{List of Tables}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1.1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\LARGE A
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.2}

\section{Section 1.2}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2.1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2.2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 2.1}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.1}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2}

\section{Section 2.2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}

\endmatter

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**
The solution I have in mind would behave similarly to what I assume is default hyperref behavior for sections and subsections: the hypertarget points to the title, regardlessly of where in the text that title is placed.

I tried adding something along the following lines in the preamble, using the etoolbox package and the `\apptocmd` command.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\apptocmd{\contentsname}{\hypertarget{tocpage}{}}{}{}
}
\makeatother
```

Of course, I commented out the existing `\hypertarget{tocpage}` in the MWE.

When I run the MWE with this code, I get the following error:

```
[1]./Thesis.toc !Missing control sequence inserted <inserted text> \inaccessible.
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong in the command definition?

Answer (score 5):

Your `listsof` start a new page *after* `hypertarget` has chosen the target page. One way round this would be to insert a `\cleardoublepage` or a `clearpage` before `hypertarget`:

```
\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{lofpage}{}
\listoffigures
\bookmark[dest=lofpage]{List of Figures}
```

Of course, if you were to use the `memoir` document class, you could use `\clearforchapter`, which is more semantic, and adjusts automatically for oneside/twoside.

Comment: This does help, but I'm looking at a solution that links to the title. This is the default behavior for sections, subsections, etc., where you do not need or should clear the page. I've posted an update of my preliminary attempts to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

`hyperref` automatically defines something equivalent to the `\hypertarget`s you are trying to insert, and already in the correct locations. Following a `\chapter*`, the name of the immediately preceding anchor is stored in `\@currentHref`. Therefore, in your `\bookmark` commands, you need only refer to `\@currentHref` (either with `\makeatletter` active or via `\csname @currentHref\endcsname`). Here, I have defined a macro `\bookmarkCurrentHref` in the preamble to save having to use `@` in the document body:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot,chapter]{tocbibind}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bookmarkCurrentHref}[1][]{\bookmark[dest=\@currentHref,#1]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\bookmarkCurrentHref{Table of Contents}

\makeatletter
\listoffigures
\bookmarkCurrentHref{List of Figures}

\listoftables
\bookmarkCurrentHref{List of Tables}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1.1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\LARGE A
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.2}

\section{Section 1.2}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2.1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2.2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 2.1}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.1}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2}

\section{Section 2.2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}

%\endmatter
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

---

As well as offering a solution to your problem, I'll try to explain why your attempts were not successful (note that any code here is offered as explanation only and I strongly suggest using the above approach in preference to anything here):

- Your patch to `\contentsname` causes issues because the macro is used more than once. In particular, it is used for setting the chapter name and is passed to `\@mkboth`. Here is the definition of `\tableofcontents` in effect in your MWE, revealed by `\show\tableofcontents` just after `\begin{document}`:

  ```
  \if@twocolumn \@restonecoltrue \onecolumn \else \@restonecolfalse \fi \chapter *{\contentsname \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }{\MakeUppercase \contentsname }}\@starttoc {toc}\if@restonecol \twocolumn \fi
  ```
- If you were to manually redefine `\tableofcontents` so that only the first `\contentsname` is affected, it works as you expect:

  ```
  \def\tableofcontents{\if@twocolumn \@restonecoltrue \onecolumn \else \@restonecolfalse \fi \chapter *{\hypertarget{tocpage}{}\contentsname \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }{\MakeUppercase \contentsname }}\@starttoc {toc}\if@restonecol \twocolumn \fi}
  ```

  (Note that this needs surrounding with `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`.)

  Patching this with `etoolbox` would not be entirely trivial/minimal due to the `\@mkboth` also being part of the argument to the `\chapter*`.
- Similarly for the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, except the `\@mkboth` is not part of the argument to `\chapter*` in those cases which makes them easier to patch, eg (though again, I don't suggest you do it):

  ```
  \patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter *{\listfigurename }}{\chapter*{\hypertarget{lofpage}{}\listfigurename}}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
  ```

  (Note that this does not need surrounding with `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`.)